# What are some properties that imply that a group must be the trivial group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, soft-question, big-list

In the problem posed in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/659165/if-a-b-triangleleft-g-where-g-a-is-perfect-and-g-b-is-solvable-then-ab) question of mine we want to show that a particular group is both perfect and solvable, and therefore trivial, and this turns out to be useful in proving the result.

What other combinations of properties required of a group imply that it must be isomorphic to the trivial group?

Answer (score 8):

$G$ is trivial if any of the following hold.

- $|G|$ is odd and every element is conjugate to its inverse
- $G$ is cyclic and some group $H$ exists such that $H/Z(H)\cong G$ (equivalently, $G\cong \operatorname{Inn}(H)$)
- $|G|=n^2$ and $G$ has an irreducible representation of dimension $n$
- given any group $H$, there is precisely one group homomorphism $f:G\rightarrow H$.
- given any group $H$, there is precisely one group homomorphism $f:H\rightarrow G$.
- $G$ is solvable, not isomorphic to $S_3$, and all of its conjugacy classes have distinct sizes
- $G$ is finitely generated, nilpotent, not $\mathbb{Z}_2$, and every automorphism is inner

Comment: Nice, thanks.  Under what conditions is an element conjugate to its inverse?  If $g^{-1}xg=x^{-1}$ then $xg=gx^{-1}$, so $g$ commutes with $x$ up to taking inverses.  Is there a formal way to describe this?

Comment: @AlexPetzke Hm, can you clarify your question?  My inclination is to reply that your comment is precisely the formal description, but I'm sure that's not what you want.

Comment: I suppose I was just hoping for something interesting that's at a higher level than just simple computation with elements, involving properties of $C_G(x)$ since this influences $\mathrm{cl}(x)$, or something along those lines.  If there isn't anything like that I can certainly accept that too.  I'm just trying to think and go a little deeper.

Answer (score 3):

If the automorphism group og a group $G$ is trivial, then $G$ must be the trivial group or $\mathbf{Z}/2$. This is a nice qualifying-exam-type exercise. Although this includes two possibilities it is (hopefully) in the spirit of what you asked.

Comment: $G$'s got to be finite too, I think.

Comment: Thanks Alex Gruber. I realized as soon as I posted but you were too fast before my edit!

Comment: I believe finiteness is not needed although the proof is bit harder.

Comment: Finiteness is certainly not needed - although choice may be

Comment: You're right.  I was thinking of something else (where a Tarski monster was a counterexample).

Comment: For the infinite case, note that the group must be abelian (because the inner automorphism group is trivial), and then note that inverting elements is an automotphism. Thus, all elements must have order two, and so the group must be a direct sum of some cyclic groups of order 2 (this step may need choice). Swapping these elements is an automotphism, so the group is either cyclic of order two or trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this is welcome:

If $G$ has exactly 1 element

If $G$ is finite and divisible

If $G$ is abelian, simple, and does not have prime order

Comment: But the trivial group is not simple, so there are no groups at all that satisfy your third condition.